# CSS Animation Make Disappear Completely

Tags: css, animation

I am currently trying to adjust the CSS Animation I have testing on https://www.alexcurriemedia.com/css-test/

What I need to happen is for the first image to not be on screen when the page opens, and for the last image to disappear completely off screen

Here is the html code:

```
<table><td><h1 class="animated slideInLeft">
<img src="https://www.alexcurriemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/18.jpg" height="500" width="500"/>
</h1></td>
<td><h1 class="animated slideOutRight">
<img src="https://www.alexcurriemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/18.jpg" height="100" width="500"/>
</h1></td></table>
```

And [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/5ycvkq08/2/#&togetherjs=uFyAUIA2Sg) is the stylesheet for the movements:

Comment: I don't understand properly. Cannot you just use `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` properties from CSS?

Comment: Your link doesn't work?

Comment: The problem is in your js fiddle, you cannot transition visibilty in keyframes, you can transition opacity or use javascript to toggle display:block; to display:none;

Answer (score 0):

So on load you want the image on the right to start sliding off the page, and the image on the left to start sliding in?

Your images are staying visible after they slide over because, by default, content that overflow's it's parent stays visible. Try adding `overflow: hidden` to `.content-wrapper`.

Otherwise I've misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your js fiddle, you cannot transition visibilty in keyframes, it is either visible or not visible, so theres no mid-points to 'transition' you can how-ever transition opacity or use javascript to toggle display:block; to display:none; or combine the two methods to fade out its visiblity and then remove it from the dom using js.

Also your keyframe statements should both match:
ie from: should have all the same properties & values
as 'to'.

examples:

```
@keyframes name{
  from{filter:opacity(0) hue-rotate(0deg);}
  to{filter:opacity(1) hue-rotate(288deg);}
}

@keyframes sumName{
  0%{filter:opacity(0) hue-rotate(0deg);}        // Note even though hue-rotate is at 0deg, it will not run if they do not match
  50%{filter:opacity(0.5) hue-rotate(288deg);}
  100%{filter:opacity(1) hue-rotate(24degdeg);}
}
```

Also:
These`should be above the keyframe declarations, symantically speaking.

```
.slideInLeft {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInLeft;
  animation-name: slideInLeft;
}
```

hope some of these help.